# MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: 'newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, rest, aggregation-framework

I am getting an error if I try to fetch the users from the aggregation I have created for my mongodb.

```
const users = await locations.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [req.query.longitude, req.query.latitude],
          },
          maxDistance: 2000,
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          spherical: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "userId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user",
        },
      },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          userId: 1,
          name: 1,
          profession: 1,
          hide: 1,
          profilePhotoLink: 1,
          uid: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $limit: pageSize,
      },
      {
        $skip: pageSize * (req.query.page - 1),
      },
    ]);
```

It was working fine and I was getting the users in an array but now, it's throwing an error.

Error:

```
code: 500,
  error: 'Server Error',
  api: '/api/users?longitude=77.3720925&latitude=28.6851771&distance=250&page=1',
  level: 'error',
  message: MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: 'newRoot' expression  must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: MISSING. Type of resulting value: 'missing'. Input document: {_id: 64c4bfc46c4590160ec0e6cc, userId: 64c4bfb66c459012fac0e6c6, location: {coordinates: [180.3721, 21.6852], type: "Point"}, createdAt: 2023-07-29T07:29:08.311Z, updatedAt: 2023-07-29T07:29:08.311Z, __v: 0, dist: {calculated: 2.12997}, user: []}
```

I don't know why it's failing and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's because for some specific filter (`longitude=77.3720925&latitude=28.6851771&distance=250`) no users exist in the db, and so you have empty array after `$lookup` and next step fails with 500.

Perhaps you can simply filter out using `$match` points without any users found:

```
const users = await locations.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [req.query.longitude, req.query.latitude],
      },
      maxDistance: 2000,
      distanceField: "dist.calculated",
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user",
    },
  },
  { 
    $match: { 
      "user.0": {
        "$exists": true 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$user", 0],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      userId: 1,
      name: 1,
      profession: 1,
      hide: 1,
      profilePhotoLink: 1,
      uid: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $limit: pageSize,
  },
  {
    $skip: pageSize * (req.query.page - 1),
  },
]);
```